# Algorithm for dividing student into N groups

Tags: algorithm, graph, grouping

I would like to divide M students into N teams. It's not hard, but there are some contraints.

1.constraint: (A,B) A pair of students must be together in one group. It means that studentA want to be in a same group as studentB.

2.constraints: (A,B) A pair of students (studentA and studentB) mustn't be in one group.

I have M students and want to create N groups by this constraints. If it's not possible to divide them, find the best solution with minimum violations of constraints.

Any idea how to solve it by algorithm?

Comment: It's **your** homework, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it useful to think of this as a [graph colouring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).  The link contains various suggested algorithms.

The vertices represent the students, and the colours represent different groups.

An edge between vertices represents that those students want to be in different groups.  If students want to be in the same group, simply merge the vertices.

Unfortunately, even when placing students into just 3 groups this proves that your problem is NP-hard (because you could use it to find a 3-colour for a graph - and this problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Computational_complexity))